# XPath - how to select node with multiple attribute values?

Tags: html, xml, dom, xpath, simple-html-dom

Assume:

```
<foo bar="one two three">
```

How do I match all the `foo` tags that has the attribute `bar` with the value `one` (and I don't care what other attribute values might exist). This doesn't seem to work:

```
//foo[@bar="one"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XPath 1.0 or 2.0

The standard idiom for that is:

```
//foo[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@bar), ' '), ' one ')]
```

### XPath 2.0

```
//foo[tokenize(@bar,'\s+')='one']
```

Comment: Almost in sync. Your answer is definitely correct :-).

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is

```
//foo[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@bar), " "), " one ")]
```

Comment: Haha.  I'd call it a tie.  (+1)